# Can I keep a python script running in the cloud?

Tags: python, cloud, hosting, reddit, praw

I have a simple 1-file python reddit bot that requires 3 packages (2 standard library), and read/write access to one text file, or any other system I could use to store data. I want it to run 24/7, but I don't care about downtime. I want some sort of service that lets me do this for free, without requiring me to enter payment info, but preferably free forever.

I tried AWS, but it requires a credit card and I did something with Heroku a while ago, but they got rid of their free tier. I also looked at digitalOcean, but it's not free.

Comment: Asking for recommendations for such services or tools, libraries,... are offtopic here.

Comment: well other people made similar questions about PAID services so its legal.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried finding a free service for this purpose but have not been able to; I went with using an old junk PC that I run 24/7 instead. You could also use a raspberry pi but they are expensive nowadays.